# Script to capitalize first char of first two words through split returning java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Here is the excerpt in which I encounter the error: `

```
String[] splitbyspace = search.split(" ");

if(splitbyspace.length > 2){
    String spacesplitted = splitbyspace[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + splitbyspace[0].substring(1) + " " + splitbyspace[1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + splitbyspace[1].substring(1);
    searchIdx = content.indexOf(spacesplitted);

    if(searchIdx != -1){
        String sentence = content.substring(searchIdx+search.length()+1, content.indexOf('.', searchIdx));
        sentence = sentence.replace("\"", "");
        sentences.add(sentence);
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at Untitled2.taste(Untitled2.java:127)
    at Untitled2.answer(Untitled2.java:69)
    at Untitled2.main(Untitled2.java:29)
```

What am I doing wrong in terms of looping the indices? The content of String `search` is:

`george bush is`

and I want `String spacesplitted` to make it into

`George Bush is`.

But that's not happening.

The exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range` thrown is at 27, but corresponds to line 3 in the code block in the above excerpt. It is where `String spacesplitted` is used.

Comment: Please format your code. Have you tried a debugger? In which line of the shown code is the Exception thrown?

Comment: Fixed & added info @MrSmith42

Comment: what is your `content` and is the `searchIdx` at beginning `0`?

Comment: What about simply print the `spacesplitted` to the console to have a look if it contains, what you expect?

Comment: Content contains "George Bush is"

Comment: so the problem appears with `content.substring` i think

Comment: a line with lots of '.' and statements is quite hard to debug - as a lot of stuff happens in one line. For debugging purposes it helps a lot to split the statements into different lines and save the values in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code whit this at start

```
String content = "George Bush is";
int searchIdx;
```

and it works (at least line with exception - second if has another problem). Think, the problem is that `search` has spaces at the beginning or double spaces inside, and your `splitbyspace` has some empty strings. Try to store each step's result in separate variable and run it in debug. Also, to make it really error-proof, read closely [String#split javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) - it has some interesting things.

And finally, if this code is not just for education, I recommend you use some libraries, where words capitalization/splitting to sentences are already implemented.